# Could not load tiled map in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

I have been following this tutorial [LIBGDX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8jgD-V5jG8&list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt&index=6) . I followed the similar steps as per the tutorial but the map is not loaded in the background as per the tutorial. I checked the code but I couldn't find the reason .

Here is my code,

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
private MyJungleGame game;
Texture texture;
private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
private FitViewport gamePort;
private HudClass hud;
private TmxMapLoader maploader; 
private TiledMap map; 
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer; 
public PlayScreen(MyJungleGame game) {
    this.game = game;

    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MyJungleGame.V_WIDTH, MyJungleGame.V_HEIGHT);
    hud = new HudClass(game.batch);
    maploader = new TmxMapLoader();

    map = maploader.load("tiledmap.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map); 
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

}


public void update(float dt) {
handleInput(dt);
 gamecam.update(); 
 renderer.setView(gamecam); // it wil draw wat the game cam can see
}

public void handleInput(float dt) { //(----4)
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        gamecam.position.x += 100 * dt; 
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta); 
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     renderer.render(); 

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined); 
    hud.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    gamePort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

This is my main game code . I have attached the screenshot of the output[image: output] .
   As you can see it is filled with black background but I need the tiled map to get loaded. I am completely new to this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I just found it. The problem is in the gameport. I didn't pass the value of camera to the gameport. I just changed the code from

```
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MyJungleGame.V_WIDTH, MyJungleGame.V_HEIGHT);
```

to something like,

```
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MyJungleGame.V_WIDTH,  MyJungleGame.V_HEIGHT,gamecam);
```